# Java inner class new instance not being created

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I have a `Java` class that is going to have a number of inner classes. This is done for organization and to keep things in a separate file.

```
public class PUCObjects
{

    public static class PUCNewsItem
    {

        public String title;
        public String summary;
        public String body;
        public String url;
        public String imageUrl;

    }

}
```

I am then trying to create a new instance of that inner class (doing this in another class that parses some remote XML), but for some reason it doesn't seem to get created:

```
public static ArrayList<PUCObjects.PUCNewsItem> getPUCNews() throws IOException {

        String url = "http://api.puc.edu/news/list?key="+API_KEY+"&count=30";
        InputStream is = downloadUrl(url);
        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);

            ArrayList<PUCObjects.PUCNewsItem> items = null;
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            PUCObjects.PUCNewsItem item = null;
            Log.d("Debug: ", "Start: "+url);
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                String name = null;
                switch (eventType){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        items = new ArrayList<PUCObjects.PUCNewsItem>();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        name = parser.getName();
                        //Log.d("Start Tag Name: ", parser.getName()+"  ===  "+name);
                        if (name == "item"){
                            Log.d("Debug: ", "Item");
                            item = new PUCObjects.PUCNewsItem();
                        } else if (item != null){
                            Log.d("Debug: ", "Item is not NULL 2");
                            if (name == "title"){
                                Log.d("Title: ", parser.nextText());
                                item.title = parser.nextText();
                            } else if (name == "summary"){
                                item.summary = parser.nextText();
                            } else if (name == "body_text"){
                                item.body = parser.nextText();
                            }  
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && item != null) {
                            Log.d("Debug: ", "ADD ITEM");
                            items.add(item);
                        }
                        break;
                }//end switch

                eventType = parser.next();

            }//end while

            Log.d("Debug: ", "Done");
            return items;

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }//end
```

I am trying to create the object like `item = new PUCObjects.PUCNewsItem();` but it seems to always be `null`.

**Is there a reason why this is object isn't getting created?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is `String` comparison. Your `if` statement is not resulting to `true` due to `==` check.

```
if (name == "item"){
```

You need to use `equals()` method instead of `==` when comparing Objects/Strings. Read this thread for more information on [eqauals() vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)